# why i got so many modules deleted after installing dotenv?

Tags: node.js, npm, mern, dotenv

I am getting this totally unexpected problem: after installing dotenv, whenever I run `npm start` i get the error `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'body-parser' imported from`. before installing dotenv, everything was working fine. should i install body-parser over again?
these are modules (presumably deleted) appearing crossed out:
[image]

To be more precise, this is what I am getting after running `npm start`:

```
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'body-parser' imported from C:\Users\Lenovo\desktop\projects\posts\server\index.js
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:674:9)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:715:14)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:808:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:82:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:226:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Any advice on what should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't have node_modules in source control, anyway

Comment: @OneCricketeer so, do you mean that if i had had .gitignore file, this problem wouldn't have occured?

Comment: No, I'm saying that all the crossed out items aren't the actual issue since they shouldn't be shown, anyway. Something else deleted those files

Answer (score 1):

Remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`

`node_modules` is managed by npm, so let it do its job. If you ever miss with that folder remove it and reinstall packages using `npm install`

Also, as mentioned in the comments above, you should not submit it to version control, because it can be derived from `package.json`. It's just more storage that's not needed.

Just a note, You don't need to install body-parser anymore. It's already included in recent versions of express as `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`